# Wagtail: Setting a dedicated Static folder for each app in Multisite

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am using Multisite to administer several websites and a custom admin on a single build of Wagtail. Currently, I have my static folder set like this:

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'websites.sua_umn_edu',
    'admin_sua_umn_edu',
    ...
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Is there some way to set the `STATIC_URL` dynamically, so each app looks for a static directory within its own folder?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a template tag that creates a path based on the `request.site` fits your needs? I created a template tag for a per site stylesheet:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('website/tags/stylesheet.html', takes_context=True)
def stylesheet(context):
    slug = slugify(context['request'].site)
    return {
        'path': '/css/{}/main.css'.format(slug)
    }
```

website/tags/stylesheet.html

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static path %}">
```

This template tag can be used in your base.html

```
{% stylesheet %}
```

Maybe stylesheets is too limited for your websites but this concept can be generalised. Here is pseudo code for a `{% site_static '...' %}` template tag. It looks up the current site and calls the normal static template tag.

```
from django.templatetags.static import do_static


@register.tag('site_static', takes_context=True)
def site_static(context, parser, token)
    site_slug = slugify(context['request'].site)
    token = '{}/{}'.format(site_slug, token)
    return do_static(parser, token)
```